# How to assign value to multi-value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I want to assign All `SkinThickness` zero value with the mean of each patient 
 lies in certain range of `Age`.

So I grouped data-frame by `Age` to get the mean of `SkinThickness` for each age range.

In order to assign every **Zero** value in `SkinThickness` Column to the corresponding mean value computed from the age grouping.

```py
ageSkinMean = df_clean.groupby("Age_Class")["SkinThickness"].mean()
>>> ageSkinMean

Age_Class
21-22 years     82.163399
23-25 years    103.171429
26-30 years     91.170254
31-38 years     80.133028
39-47 years     73.685851
48-58 years     89.130233
60+ years       40.899160
Name: Insulin, dtype: float64
```

Currently I'm running such insufficient code ... which takes too long time for using `iterrows()`

```py
start = time.time()
for i, val in df_clean[df_clean.SkinThickness == 0].iterrows():
    if val[7] < 22:
        df_clean.loc[i, "SkinThickness"] = ageSkinMean[0]
    elif val[7] < 25:
        df_clean.loc[i, "SkinThickness"] = ageSkinMean[1]
    elif val[7] < 30:
        df_clean.loc[i, "SkinThickness"] = ageSkinMean[2]
    elif val[7] < 38:
        df_clean.loc[i, "SkinThickness"] = ageSkinMean[3]
    elif val[7] < 47:
        df_clean.loc[i, "SkinThickness"] = ageSkinMean[4]
    elif val[7] < 58:
        df_clean.loc[i, "SkinThickness"] = ageSkinMean[5]
    else:
        df_clean.loc[i, "SkinThickness"] = ageSkinMean[6]
print(time.time() - start)
```

I wonder if there exist any **pandas** optimization to such block of code **to run faster**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas transform function to replace SkinThickness 0 value with mean values

```
    age_skin_thickness_mean = df_clean.groupby('Age_Class')['SkinThickness'].mean()

    def replace_with_mean_thickness(row):
       row['SkinThickness'] = age_skin_thickness_mean[row['Age_Class']]
       return row

    df_clean.loc[df_clean['SkinThickness'] == 0] = df_clean.loc[df_clean['SkinThickness'] == 0].transform(replace_with_mean_thickness, axis=1)
```

All rows having SkinThickness == 0 in df_clean will now have SkinThickness equal to their age group mean value.